# Linking to a specific part of a table from other website?

Tags: hyperlink

I want to link a specific table raw to my website from (QAI) website.

below the website image https://pasteboard.co/IVocPqq.jpg

there are lots of tr tags how to target one of them?

I want to link only a specific raw so when people click the link they will be directed to that raw.

Comment: `<a href=link.com><tr>...</tr></a>` :D

Comment: it didn't work. It just opens the page.